# Access wordpress with both http and https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, https

Why 'http://example.com/post' and 'https://example.com/post' direct to different page? How to fix it? I want to redirect http tp https wordpress page. This is my .htaccess code

```
<IfModule Litespeed>
SetEnv noabort 1
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /post/index.php [L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.yourdomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanen
</IfModule>
```

---

Comment: Unclear what you are asking - when I test both of the URLs you mention, they both appear to show exactly the same content.

Comment: Try in a different browser, or on a different machine. If that works, then clear your browser history, it might simply be an old faulty redirect that got cached.

Comment: `[END,QSA,R=permanen` - the last part of the `RewriteRule` directive is missing and consequently is syntactically invalid (ie. results in a 500 error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless if you have changed the configuration of the Apache, the site doesn't have any problem and the problem that you are facing is a local problem because of the cache.

The cache could be stored either on your browser or on your Wifi Router or inside your Internet Local Service Provider.

For future case, I advise to test the website on a TorBrowser where you not gonna have a cache problem,

Comment: "test the website on a TorBrowser" - Or simply test with browser dev tools open and the "disable cache" checkbox checked.

Comment: @MrWhite will the dev tools solve the problem if your local ISP had already cached a version of the website? one time it took me 3 days till my local ISP removed the cache

Comment: No it won't. Just saying that disabling local caching will be sufficient in the vast majority of cases.